# Update array elements position in mongo object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an object ( document ) in mongo with the below structure

```
{
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'value2',
    'array1' : [5, 2, 10, 11]
}
```

Now I want to change `array1` as `[5, 10, 2, 11]` by swapping 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> elements of array.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to shuffle around array element. You need to figure out which one will be most efficient.

e.g. In your case, it's much easier to fix array indexes on client and make a single update request to server.

```
db.collection.update(
   {key1:"value1", key2:"value2"},
   {$set:{array1:[5,10,2,11]}}
)
```

With the help of above query, your resultant document will be

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("571dfcdce6d693e88c38242f"), 
    "key1" : "value1", 
    "key2" : "value2", 
    "array1" : [
        5.0, 
        10.0, 
        2.0, 
        11.0
    ]
}
```

However, if you want to do experimentation, see [$position](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) operator

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Saleem, It solve my problem. But is there no other way to do this instead of set full array, just by changing the position of array element and save full object?